# Make dict from array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I want to make a dictionary from a given array.

I have this one.

```
{1: (0, 4, 12, 27, 25, 58),
 2: (4, 0, 24, 16, 29, 38),
 3: (12, 24, 0, 31, 14, 30),
 4: (27, 16, 31, 0, 21, 8),
 5: (25, 29, 14, 21, 0, 11),
 6: (58, 38, 30, 8, 11, 0)}
```

And I want to get this

```
{1: {1: 0, 2: 4, 3: 12, 4: 27, 5: 25, 6: 58},
 2: {1: 4, 2: 0, 3: 24, 4: 16, 5: 29, 6: 38},
 3: {1: 12, 2: 24, 3: 0, 4: 31, 5: 14, 6: 30},
 4: {1: 27, 2: 16, 3: 31, 4: 0, 5: 21, 6: 8},
 5: {1: 25, 2: 29, 3: 14, 4: 21, 5: 0, 6: 11},
 6: {1: 58, 2: 38, 3: 30, 4: 8, 5: 11, 6: 0}}
```

How can I get this?

Comment: You might be interested in `enumerate()` as the core of your answer

Comment: what did you already try?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any arrays, it looks like you have a dictionary containing tuple values.

You can use a dictionary comprehension along with `enumerate()` to get the desired results.

```
new_dict = {key: dict(enumerate(value, 1)) for key, value in old_dict.items()}
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `.items()`